# How to call a JS function using OnClick event

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to call my JS function that I added in the header. Please find below the code that shows my problem scenario.

Note: I don't have access to the body in my application.

Every time I click on the element with `id="Save"` it only calls `f1()` but not `fun()`. How can I make it call even my `fun()`?

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>

  <script>

   document.getElementById("Save").onclick = function fun()
    {
     alert("hello");
     //validation code to see State field is mandatory.  
    }   

    function f1()
    {
       alert("f1 called");
       //form validation that recalls the page showing with supplied inputs.    
    }

  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form name="form1" id="form1" method="post">
            State: 
            <select id="state ID">
               <option></option>
               <option value="ap">ap</option>
               <option value="bp">bp</option>
            </select>
   </form>

   <table><tr><td id="Save" onclick="f1()">click</td></tr></table>

   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: `f1` should not be called at all, because you have a runtime error. See also [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as `getElementById` not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/218196). But anyways, `func` does not run because you are not calling it anywhere.

Answer (score 47):

You are attempting to attach an event listener function before the element is loaded. Place `fun()` inside an `onload` event listener function. Call `f1()` within this function, as the `onclick` attribute will be ignored.

```
function f1() {
    alert("f1 called");
    //form validation that recalls the page showing with supplied inputs.    
}
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("Save").onclick = function fun() {
        alert("hello");
        f1();
        //validation code to see State field is mandatory.  
    }
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/cKYD4/)

Answer (score 19):

You could use addEventListener to add as many listeners as you want.

```
  document.getElementById("Save").addEventListener('click',function ()
    {
     alert("hello");
     //validation code to see State field is mandatory.  
    }  );
```

Also add `script` tag after the element to make sure `Save` element is loaded at the time when script runs

Rather than moving script tag you could call it when dom is loaded. Then you should place your code inside the

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById("Save").addEventListener('click',function ()
    {
     alert("hello");
     //validation code to see State field is mandatory.  
    }  ); 
});
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/L2Q87/)

Answer (score 7):

I removed your `document.getElementById("Save").onclick =` before your functions, because it's an event already being called on your button. I also had to call the two functions separately by the onclick event.

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
      <head>
      <script>
       function fun()
        {
         alert("hello");
         //validation code to see State field is mandatory.  
        }   
        function f1()
        {
          alert("f1 called");
           //form validation that recalls the page showing with supplied inputs.    
        }
      </script>
      </head>
      <body>
      <form name="form1" id="form1" method="post">
                State: 
                <select id="state ID">
                   <option></option>
                   <option value="ap">ap</option>
                   <option value="bp">bp</option>
                </select>
       </form>

       <table><tr><td id="Save" onclick="f1(); fun();">click</td></tr></table>

   </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Using the `onclick` attribute or applying a function to your JS `onclick` properties will erase your `onclick` initialization in `<head>`.

What you need to do is *add* click events on your button. To do that you’ll need the `addEventListener` or `attachEvent` (IE) method.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function addEvent(obj, event, func) {
            if (obj.addEventListener) {
                obj.addEventListener(event, func, false);
                return true;
            } else if (obj.attachEvent) {
                obj.attachEvent('on' + event, func);
            } else {
                var f = obj['on' + event];
                obj['on' + event] = typeof f === 'function' ? function() {
                    f();
                    func();
                } : func
            }
        }

        function f1()
        {
            alert("f1 called");
            //form validation that recalls the page showing with supplied inputs.    
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="form1" id="form1" method="post">
        State: <select id="state ID">
        <option></option>
        <option value="ap">ap</option>
        <option value="bp">bp</option>
        </select>
    </form>

    <table><tr><td id="Save" onclick="f1()">click</td></tr></table>

    <script>
        addEvent(document.getElementById('Save'), 'click', function() {
            alert('hello');
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this with an anonymous javascript function by using a [iife](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE). **Please note that this is considered a bad practice**, though there are those rare times when there is no other option.

```
...
<span onclick="(function() { // function code here })())">click me!</span>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Inline code takes higher precedence than code from `<head>` or from a linked file. To call your other function func(), call it from the f1().

Inside your function, add a line,

```
function fun () {
// Your code here
}

function f1()
    {
       alert("f1 called");
       //form validation that recalls the page showing with supplied inputs.    

fun ();

    }
```

Rewriting your whole code,

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
    
      <script>
    
       function fun()
        {
         alert("hello");
         //validation code to see State field is mandatory.  
        }   
    
        function f1()
        {
           alert("f1 called");
           //form validation that recalls the page showing with supplied inputs.   
           fun (); 
        }
    
      </script>
      </head>
      <body>
       <form name="form1" id="form1" method="post">
    
         State: <select id="state ID">
                   <option></option>
                   <option value="ap">ap</option>
                   <option value="bp">bp</option>
                </select>
       </form>
       <table><tr><td id="Save" onclick="f1()">click</td></tr></table>
    
      </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with George. If we are to add or bind a event listener to an HTML element via JavaScript, we need to do once the DOM has been loaded. For this we can use the `window.onload()` function in JavaScript.

```
<script>
   window.onload = function() {
      document.getElementById("Save").onclick = function fun() {
        alert("hello");
      }   
   }
</script>
```

Another way is to use the `onclick` event handler in the HTML as in the following code:

```
<div onclick="myFunction()"></div>
<script>
   function myFunction() {
      alert("Hello");
   }
</script>
```

**Note:** It is NOT recommended to use both the approaches together. As it will cause two functions to be called in a single click, which is irksome.