# Javascript - Calling a function for an onClick event

Tags: javascript, function, onclick

Consider the following code :

```
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        function showAlert (text) {
            alert(text);
        }

        x = document.getElementById('aTag');
        x.setAttribute('onclick', "alert('Hello World')"); //WORKS
        x.setAttribute('onclick', "showAlert('Hello World')"); //DNW (showAlert is not defined)
    </script>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="aTag">TEST</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

The first onclick assignment works and produces a hyperlink on which, when you click on it, opens a dialog box with the `Hello World` message. Probably because the `window.alert` method is *global* (I don't know if it is the right word).

But the second assignment only returns the following error when clicked on :

```
showAlert is not defined
```

Being a beginner at JS, I think the issue might be about the `showAlert` function scope or maybe the `elementNode.setAttribute` method context in which the `showAlert` function doesn't exist.

I thank you all in advance for your time.

Regards.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Call a JS function using OnClick event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21477717/how-to-call-a-js-function-using-onclick-event)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, thanks for taking the time to reply.

In the end, I took a look at the following answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/21477793/3186538 and I ended up with this code :

```
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        // Display text function
        function showAlert(text) {
            alert("Called in showAlert: " + text);
        }
        // But for the previous function to work, we must make sure that it is loaded after the rest of the DOM
        window.onload = function() {
            document.getElementById("aTag").onclick = function fun() {
                showAlert("Hello World");
            }
        }
    </script>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="aTag">TEST</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Now, when I click on the hyperlink, I do get a dialog box showing the `Hello World` message.

Thanks again to everyone (and, of course, SO).

Answer (score 4):

At the time you're trying to get the element, it doesn't exist yet.
Move the script tag to the bottom, right before the closing body tag.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="aTag">TEST</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script>
    function showAlert (text) {
        alert(text);
    }

    x = document.getElementById('aTag');
    x.setAttribute('onclick', "alert('Hello World')"); //WORKS
    x.setAttribute('onclick', "showAlert('Hello World')"); //DNW (showAlert is not defined)
</script>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ou3t3jfo/)

You can not get an element with javascript that is not yet outputted to the DOM, so whenever you try to get an element, make sure it's available.

Answer (score 1):

Attaching it like this should do the job:

```
x.onclick = function() {showAlert("foo");};
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bjp7asfo/1/)

Comment: Is there a reason why I shouldn't use traditional event handling (the second line) in Firefox?

Comment: @FelixKling Nope. Just me being hasty. Updated.

Comment: Indeed, your syntax is short AND does the job perfectly. Thanks !