# Error onclick button code wrong?

Tags: php

I have an `onclick` on a button but it is not working properly.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button" onclick=\'websiteopen("'.$site->page_id.'","fb"), PopupCenter("http://nullrefer.com/?'.$site->facebook.'","Website", "'.$site->id.'", "'.$site->title.'", 1000,500,"fb");jqxAlert.alert("Verifying..<img src=\'http://website.com/_template/images/load.gif'>");$(this).fadeOut().delay(4100).fadeIn();\'><b class="glyphicons thumbs_up" style="height:8px;vertical-align:baseline;padding:2px 9px"><i></i></b> '.$lang['sp17'].'</a>
```

It is something wrong in this part of the code:

```
jqxAlert.alert("Verifying..<img src=\'http://website.com/_template/images/load.gif'>");
```

What is the issue?

Comment: you need to learn basic Javascript string syntax...

Comment: what's your text part for this href?

Comment: You need to put the onclick value inside quotes (most likely single quotes), you need to close the `<a` tag (missing `>`), you need some text in the `<a>` tag.

Comment: @zairwolf added more details tnx

Comment: @XDesign you should simplify your question. Also make sure if its about HTML or PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You formatting is wrong, it needs to be as follows:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button" onclick="jqxAlert.alert('Verifying...')">
    <img src="_template/images/load.gif" height="16px">
</a>
```

**Edit:**
This answer assumes that the code above is using a plugin that behaves in a similar manner to the window.alert(); similar to something like this -> http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-alert-popup/

Comment: Considering that this is a js alert box (not the window.alert function) (it appears to be something like a jquery alert). If so it would likely be able to accept the image tag (and other html) as part of the text.

Comment: Agreed, but I did a quick search for the plugin (found this: http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-alert-popup/) which appears to just be a styled equivalent of the js window.alert(); I will add the reference to make this clear

Comment: Feel like giving anymore details than that?

Comment: You haven't made any of the changes I suggested, so it's still broken

Answer (score 0):

be carefull with the double quotes. In html you can write simple quotes inside double quotes and it is translate good.

');"

Or use functions:

[Functions on clic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21477717/how-to-call-a-js-function-using-onclick-event)