# Change CONFIG [CLIENT SIDE] in Tampermonkey

Tags: javascript

[CONFIG.PNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpebc.png) <--

**How to change the Config in Tampermonkey if i change it there it works but i want to do it in Tampermonkey does that work and how?**

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a button in the example code. Can you show the button, and what you have tried, something relevant to the question ...

Comment: you need to see event listeners/handlers in javascript 
Click event on your button (span?) is the event you need to listen and perform required logic.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have two independent problems: a) clicking the button and b) repeating the action. I am not very sure by reading your question, but you might find `window.setInterval` useful for the second.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

As for the `onlick` event issues, you have a ton of interesting answers already there in SO, e.g. [How to Call a JS function using OnClick event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21477717/how-to-call-a-js-function-using-onclick-event)

Hope that does help.