# Apend Query String Parameter

Tags: javascript, url, parameters

I have a query string (example) `?something=1&something=3` I want to find and then add these parameters to a new URL and goto that URL on button click event.

I can find the query string using `var x =location.search;` but don't know how to add to a new URL, then use the function on button click event.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Where have you searched for the answer? There are plenty of explanations of this on the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a button like that:

```
<button type="button" onclick="redirect('mysite.html')">
```

the redirect function can look like this:

```
function redirect(target)
{
    window.location.href = target+window.location.search
}
```

---

But basically, this problem is easy to solve by divide and conquer:

[How to get the value from the GET parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters)

[How do I redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage)

[How to Call a JS function using OnClick event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21477717/how-to-call-a-js-function-using-onclick-event)

[How to prevent buttons from submitting forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932653/how-to-prevent-buttons-from-submitting-forms)